# How can I have a command constantly run?

Tags: javascript, discord.js, command

Im using Discord.js, and i would like my bot to keep a command activated until told to stop

```
client2.on('message', message => {
    if (message.content === 'grimm!record') {
        message.channel.send('Recording has Started in the Command Prompt')
        console.log(message.content)
        console.log('Grimm 2 - Recording has Started')
    }})
```

once "grimm!record" is sent in the chat, I want every message that is sent in the server to get recorded into the command prompt, but it does not seem to be working, and I also want to know if there is a way that if i send "grimm!record-stop" then all messages will stop getting sent to the command prompt

Comment: Why is it not working? Did you try to debug it?

Comment: I didnt try to debug it, but ill see if the code in the answer works

Comment: You can log message.content to see what you are getting first

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using what is called in discord.js Collector

Here is a [full guide](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/collectors.html#basic-message-collector) if you want to check it

But anyways all you want to do is start collector like

```js
// `m` is a message object that will be passed through the filter function
const filter = m => true; //A filter that accepts any type of message just returns true
const collector = message.channel.createMessageCollector(filter); //starts the collector
collector.on('collect', collectedMessage=>{
  console.log(collectedMessage.content); //console logging collected message as you wanted every message getting sent to be sent to console else use end event with map() function
  if(collecteddMessage.content === "grimm!record-stop"){ //checking message content
    collector.stop(); //ends collector
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much! it helped me out a ton!